# javascript validation not activating possibly due to php mailer on HTML form

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation, mailer

I have a problem with my Javascript validation not activating. I also have a PHP mailer on this HTML form and as soon as submit is pressed it submits the form and no validation is done.

Here is the code for the HTML form:

```
 <form name="contact" action="mailer.php" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method="post"><fieldset>

<tr><td><label for="name">Name:</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />
</td></tr>

<tr><td><label for="email">Email:</label></td>
<td><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
</td></tr>

<tr><td><label for="tel">Phone:</label></td>
<td><input type="tel" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Enter your phone number" />
</td></tr>

<tr><td><label for="message">Message:</label></td>
<td><textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder=""></textarea>
</td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is the code for the PHP mailer:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$to = "email@address.com.au";
$subject = "Subject";
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$tel_field = $_POST ['tel'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Phone: $tel_field\n Message:\n $message";


mail($to, $subject, $body, "From: $email_field");
echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
echo "<a href='index.html'>Go back to Home Page</a>";
} else {
echo "error";
}
?>
```

Here is the code for the validator:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

{function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["contact"]["name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Name field must be filled out");
  return false;
  }

   var x=document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }

 var x=document.forms["contact"]["tel"].value;
if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Phone number must be provided");
  return false;
  }

  var x=document.forms["contact"]["message"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("You have not entered a message");
  return false;
  }

  </script>
```

I have tried putting the javascript validator in as a separate file on the server or the script itself in the form html document and neither way seems to work. I have done a lot of searching and have checked the code and am pretty sure it's right however could not find anything to say whether or not these two functions are possible together. If someone could please confirm that it would be awesome!

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Kaz

Comment: when does validateForm() gets called ?

Comment: Are there any javascript errors? You can catch them in your Chrome browser or Firebug debugger ...

Comment: show us the <form> open tag as well....

Comment: where is the function's closing parenthesis?

Comment: I've never used FF debugging before. Just installed Firebug and can't see any issues.

Sry never used this site before, getting used to the coding of the msg. Forgot to hit enter.

I had closing parenthesis but then a bunch of scripts I looked at online didn't have them they just looked like this so I removed them so they looked the same just incase that was the problem.

Comment: Just realized I missed the enter for all of them. All codes now should be appearing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `onSubmit` you are calling `return ValidateForm()` when you should be doing `return validateForm()` with a lowercase "v". There are some others:

`{function validateForm()` should be `function validateForm()`

You never close the functions opening brace after the if statement.

```
<form name="contact" action="mailer.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

and then:

```
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["contact"]["name"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Name field must be filled out");
        return false;
    }

    var x = document.forms["contact"]["email"].value;
    var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (atpos < 1 || dotpos < atpos + 2 || dotpos + 2 >= x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }

    var x = document.forms["contact"]["tel"].value;
    if (y == null || y == "") {
        alert("Phone number must be provided");
        return false;
    }

   var x = document.forms["contact"]["message"].value;
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("You have not entered a message");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It was lower case until i read somewhere else that there's was solved by changing to uppercase. >.< I've tried this both ways and neither work.
I just read through what you wrote for your second comment about not closing the opening brace. And it's exactly the same as my code just reformatted a little.
So unfortunately this does not resolve the problem.

Comment: @kazie151 If what you posted is your code, then your code is wrong and it needs to be changed. What I posted above, works. You admitted to it being the same (not closing the functions opening brace) and yet you say that it won't resolve the issue? If you don't close a brace, it is going to cause an error and you won't get the result you want

Comment: I apologise I read what you wrote wrong. It's been a long day and i've got a bad headache now. Yes that worked. Thank you so much! :)